# How to change format into UTC in pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am trying to convert a DataFrame to datetime format using `pd.datetime()` but then if I try to convert the attribute further I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetime like values
```

this is my script:

````
exms_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\MandijaE\Downloads\pdwh[VE249977].csv", sep=";")``` 
    
exms_data['CHANGE_TIME.1'] = pd.to_datetime(exms_data['CHANGE_TIME.1'], format='%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S,%f %z')
    
exms_data['CHANGE_TIME.1'] = exms_data['CHANGE_TIME.1'].dt.tz_convert('UTC')
````

Comment: We need to see how your dataframe looks like

Comment: this is oen record for example: 2022-09-06 08:43:37.139000+02:00

Comment: you seem to have mixed UTC offset. pandas will parse that to vanilla Python datetime, not pandas datetime. Use `pd.to_datetime(exms_data['CHANGE_TIME.1'], format='%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S,%f %z', utc=True)` to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `CHANGE_TIME.1` column in your CSV file indeed contains values in the format `2022-09-06 08:43:37.139000+02:00`. See if it helps:

```
# Convert 'CHANGE_TIME.1' column to datetime with timezone information
exms_data['CHANGE_TIME.1'] = pd.to_datetime(exms_data['CHANGE_TIME.1'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')

# Convert timezone to UTC
exms_data['CHANGE_TIME.1'] = exms_data['CHANGE_TIME.1'].dt.tz_convert('UTC')
```